# How to draw in a panel in Java - not Jpanel

Tags: java, panel

I'm really new to Java and am working on a class project - I need to draw some pixels in a panel. I was given the jar code for the panel, and now I need to make different trails - specifically, I need to create a trail of pixels that will go around the perimeter of the panel, and I need to create some circles.

Regarding the boxes - I've gotten part of it to work. My pixels starts in the upper left corner and run to the upper right corner, go down the right side of the panel, and then it goes a little crazy - I'm not sure if it stops at the bottom right corner or goes below the bounds of the panel itself, but it doesn't complete its trip around the perimeter. My code is:

```
    import cs251.lab1.Display;

    public class Visualizer {

    private static final int PIXEL_SIZE = 50;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display panel = new Display(10, PIXEL_SIZE);
    drawWrappingDots(panel);}
    public static void drawWrappingDots(Display panel) {
        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;
        while (x > 0 && y > 0){
        if (x < panel.getWidth()){
            panel.drawNextPixel(x, y);
            x++;
        }
        if (x == panel.getWidth()){
            panel.drawNextPixel(x, y);
            y++;
        }
        if (x > 0 && y == panel.getHeight()){
            panel.drawNextPixel(x, y);
            x--;
        }
        if (x == 0 && y == panel.getHeight()){
            panel.drawNextPixel(x, y);
            y--;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Second, how do I draw a circle? I know it needs to use the math library, but I'm not sure how to go about this. Any help on this is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When doing y++ should not x be reset to 0? Or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the first question, you could use multiple if-statements:

```
int x = 1; //x starts a little to the right of 0
int y = 0; //y starts at 0
while (x > 0 && y > 0){
    if (x < panel.getWidth() && y == 0){
        panel.drawNextPixel(x, y);
        x++;
    }
    else if (x == panel.getWidth() && y != panel.getHeight()){
        panel.drawNextPixel(x, y);
        y++;
    }
    else if (x > 0 && y == panel.getHeight()){
        panel.drawNextPixel(x, y);
        x--;
    }
    else {
        panel.drawNextPixel(x, y);
        y--;
    }
}
```

This way, you check both the x and y coordinates when deciding which way you want to draw the pixels. It starts with x=1 and y=0, then moves to the right until x hits the border, then moves downward until y hits the border, then moves left until x hits 0, and finally moves upwards until y hits 0 and the while condition becomes false.

As for the circle, you need to use trigonometry. Designate a point in the middle of the panel to draw the circle. Then designate a radius you want for the circle.

```
int middle = 50;
int radius = 20;
```

Then, you use trigonometry:

```
int deg = 0;
while ( deg <= 360 ) {
  x = middle + (int)(Math.cos(deg)*radius);
  y = middle + (int)(Math.sin(deg)*radius);
  panel.drawNextPixel(x, y);
  deg++;
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Change `while` cycle to:

```
while (x > 0 && y > 0){
    if (x < panel.getWidth()){
        panel.drawNextPixel(x, y);
        x++;
    }
    if (x == panel.getWidth() && y != panel.getHeight()){
        panel.drawNextPixel(x, y);
        y++;
    }
    if (x > 1 && y == panel.getHeight()){
        panel.drawNextPixel(x, y);
        x--;
    }
    if (x == 1 && y > 0){
        panel.drawNextPixel(x, y);
        y--;
    }
```

Maybe, this is not perfect solution.